# tikz figure from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles, external-files, multiple-files

Lets say i have a tikz figure in a file called tik_fig1.tex and tik_fig2.tex with `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`

Is it then possible to add these to a main.tex with `\documentclass{article}` by referencing the files, eg as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
add(tik_fig1.tex)
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
add(tik_fig2.tex)
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

assuming all files are in the same directory.

Comment: either strip off the documentclass and `\input` the tikz, or use `\includegraphics{tik_fig1.pdf}` to include the generated output from the standalone files.

Comment: ahh thanks i will try it out :)

Comment: See also the tikzscale package.  It provides a graphicx driver for tikz (tex) files.  Standalone is more efficient, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `\usepackage{standalone}`.

```
% File-name: main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\includestandalone{input}
\end{document}
```

```
% File-name: input.tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Keep both of these files in the same directory of course. Note that you shall not add the `.tex` suffix to the argument of the `\includestandalone` command. Also you must load `tikz` in the `main.tex` file.